# How to create a quartz (cron) in Codeigniter 2 (php)?

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

I ask you how to create a quartz (cron) in with the framework of Codeigniter 2 (php), I need to send an email at 2:00 pm every day.
I await your kind support.
Regards,

Answer (score 0):

To do so, you need to add a make a `php` file that will send email. Suppose your file name is `send_email.php`. Now test that file is working or not by executing `php send_email.php` in the directory of your file. If this file sends mail successfully, then you know that this command will send email every time you execute it.

Now, you need to add this command in your Operating System's cronjob list. If you are in Linux, then open your terminal and execute the command `crontab -e`. Then select edit option to edit your cronjob. Add following line at the bottom:

`0 14 * * * php full_path_of_the_file/send_mail.php`

The first 0 means zero minute. Second number 14 means 2PM then rest three starts are for all week, months and year. then our old `php` command to execute `php` file. Then path to our created `php` file. Here, only the file won't work. You need to provide full path of your `php` file that send mail.
Save the file and exit. Now, your operating system will send email every day at 2:00PM.